# Multiple project tracking

Tags: team-management, job-allocation

I've initiated into a PM role where there is a requirement to view project health of around 30-40 projects. This includes handling resource allocation requests. Can anyone please advise on using of an excel sheet template, if this is the right approach and maybe a sample sheet. Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to Project Management Stack Exchange, a Q&A site. I think don't get your question correct: **Your a looking for a solution for the resource requests only?** By the way, if you want to learn more about how our community works, have a look at http://pm.stackexchange.com/tour.

Comment: Hi Tobias, thanks for your response. Basically I have thought of implementing an excel sheet where i have the 40 projects listed along with the status, phases complete, deadlines etc.. so the sheet will cover this aspect.. the second requirement is to work out a way to allocate resources, and if it would be feesable to allocate it in the same sheet.

Comment: Further only 1 phase is active at a given point.

Comment: I can still hardly imagine your situation. Could you expand your question? How does the process of resource allocation looks like? What kind of projects are you looking at? What's your role regarding those 40 projects?

Comment: Hi and Welcome! Are you looking for a template or at least an opinion of whether this is a good approach?

Comment: Requests for templates and other offsite resources are off topic for this site. However it is simple to set up two sheets for handling these records and you don't need a template, just some advance knowledge of what information you need to record. You already know for projects. For resource allocation- Excel is ok for this up to about 20-30 resources then it starts to get unwieldy. Use a tab per month, days down the left and names across the top, then store the project name allocated at the intersection, perhaps shaded. It is a VERY manual task, but is good for finding free slots

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your responses guys. I am kind of new to the role. I was looking to create a method of reporting to the senior management the status of projects and if escalation is required. The other aspect was resource allocation which i have to sort out per project per phase. there are generally 6-7 phases per project. Further when it comes to allocation, am looking at a way to set priorities. For instance if a resource was set to 3 projects over 3 days and there was a high importance project that required attention the other projects would be pushed automatically.Considerin excel as of now

Comment: I personally would use a free tool like Asana which allows numerous automated plugins which can then export gantt charts, healthchecks and all other manner of outputs and reporting. Disclaimer : I don't work for Asana, I just chose it out of the list of software because I like it and it is free.  *shrug*

Answer (score 1):

At one of my previous companies I replaced a 100+ slide PowerPoint deck with a simple excel spreadsheet. This was for a division that shipped close to a million units a quarter across a number of product lines.

It was highly successful. We had one tab for new projects, one tab for sustaining projects and one for field issues. My format included columns for key aspects of the projects (Software, Hardware, Packaging, etc.) so a specific area could be flagged without the whole program being flagged. Major milestone dates were then listed, which could then be flagged with a color, based on status.

At one point we were tracking over thirty different projects with this spreadsheet. The ease of use, updating and easy to digest information made it very popular. Vice presidents would print it out and put it on their wall every week when it was updated.

As for the template, this is highly context sensitive. I started out with little more than the project name and the top four milestones. I then started using it with teams and stakeholders and over the next few weeks tweaked it based on feedback. I didn't put in everyone's feedback. Instead I focused on requests made multiple times and that were not one offs.

So to wrap up, yes it's useful and start with a very simple template, grow it from there though direct use.

Comment: Thanks Joel :) and Marv!, I know now I'm going in the right direction. Will look at another sheet for allocation

Answer (score 1):

Some other ideas:

For each project,

1. number of open risk items (registered into the risks database), maybe a computed number from risk system (risk probability * risk cost / project total cost, etc)
2. number of critical issues (or an history-chart of the number of issues, to see the trends) (issues should be non-trivial ones, that is worth taking action on a decided level (your level, your higher level, or your lower level)
3. number of manhours budgeted and used (if it's more than budgeted, there might be need for re-baselining the resources or taking a better look at the issues, or updating the schedule)
4. number of releases of the project team (percentage, or XXX/YYY style) until the upcoming milestone (release can be anything, documents, technical drawings, software units, etc, depending on the scale of the project).

Coloring should be GREEN or RED, and not YELLOW, according to Takashi Tanaka (see his youtube conferences to understand why Yellow is discouraged).